# Не рендерится массив из MobxStore

Tags: reactjs, mobx

Всем привет, использую "mobx": "^6.3.3", и"react": "^18.2.0",.

Есть стор:

```
  projectList: Project[] = [];

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }

  get projectListLength() {
    console.log(Array.isArray(this.projectList));
    return this.projectList.length;
  }

  get projects() {
    return this.projectList.slice();
  }

  getAll = async (type?: ProjectTypes) => {
    const projects = await projectsService.getAll(type);
    this.projectList = toJS(projects);
  };
}
```

И есть компонент:

````
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState<ProjectTypes>("all");
  const projectsStore = new ProjectsStore();
  const tabClickHandler = (key: ProjectTypes) => {
    setActiveTab(key);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAll = async () => {
      await projectsStore.getAll(activeTab);
    };
    getAll();
    console.log("PrS: ", projectsStore);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Header>
        <PageHeader>Проекты</PageHeader>
        <Search />
      </Header>
      <Tabs
        tabs={tabs}
        activeTab={activeTab}
        tabClickHandler={tabClickHandler}
      />

      <SelfTable columns={columns} data={projectsStore.projects} />
      {projectsStore.projectListLength === 0 && <Empty />}
    </>
  );
});```


После вызова в useEffect у длина projectList 0 и ничего не рендерится. 
Консоль показывает, что projectList - это прокси.
````

Comment: Попробуйте для значений **projectsStore** создать стейт. Скорее всего реакт не понимает, что данные изменились и не осуществляет повторный рендеринг.

Comment: В observer оборачивал компонент?

Comment: @Алексей, да, оборачивал, проблема была в том, что projectsStore сделал константой, а не стейтом

Comment: @SwaD, все заработало, спасибо больше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const [projectStore] = useState(() => new ProjectsStore());`
вот так инициализровал стор и всё заработало